# Do Metro controls reuse the same codepath at low level even if controls are created from HTML/JS or XAML?

Tags: html, xaml, controls, windows-8, windows-runtime

Suppose I create two metro apps,

one with an HTML view which has

```
<input type="text"/>
```

another with a XAML based view

```
<TextBox/>
```

Does the underylying implementation map to the same code to render both controls? Will they have 100% identical behaviour?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.  The Xaml rendering stack is separate from the HTML rendering stack.  Now if you go low enough, they use the same code path - for instance both the HTML rendering stack and the Xaml rendering stack are rendered through the same display driver logic.   But the core rendering is separate.

Comment: Very useful to know.  I must have missed this in the BUILD 2011 canned 'casts.  Thanks.

Comment: Many of the HTML controls are implemented in HTML/CSS themselves.  If you look in ...\winjs\js\controls.js you will find some of them.

Comment: @Bob: I believe that every one of the presentations that discuss the UI stack has always shown that Xaml and HTML were two different rendering stacks.

Comment: @Larry: Yes, I know that.  But many of those same diagrams show IE and .Net/SL sitting on top of the Kernel too.  What's the truth about WinRT here?  Surely it sits on top of much of Win32 as well, barring GDI and other exceptions of course.  I assumed the diagrams were largely marketing.

Comment: It depends on the API.  Some of the APIs are brand new, top to bottom.  Others are written on top of existing APIs.  There were some slight errors (.Net not being there under C#, and the bottom layer being called "kernel services") but nothing huge.